# Copy Files from Source To Target Using Xcopy

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, using, xcopy

I am copying only modified files from source to target using xcopy . My code is below

```
    xcopy C:\Source\*.csv C:\Target /D /S /Y 
    xcopy C:\Source\*.txt C:\Target /D /S /Y
```

It works fine. 
But once it copies file, our running interface generate .ok file . then again file get copied over . it is continuous process.  Example:- test.txt get copy from source to target

```
    Source:- test.txt
    Target:-test.txt
```

Running interface convert test to .ok file

```
 Target:-test_07-Mar-2016_03-16-50.089.ok
```

and again file get copied and interface generate .ok file so now in target

```
 Target :- test.txt
           test_07-Mar-2016_03-16-50.089.ok
```

It happen over and over

```
Target :- test.txt
          test_07-Mar-2016_03-16-50.089.ok
          test07-Mar-2016_03-06-50.515._oK
```

Can someone help me on this one.

Comment: Why did you tag your post with [tag:using]? click on the tag and read what it means. Anyway, I don't understand the question, but perhaps you might be interested in the `/U` switch of `xcopy` to copy only files that already exist in the target (type `xcopy /?` in a command prompt window and read the help text)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
    xcopy /exclude:test.txt C:\Source\*.txt C:\Target /D /S /Y
```

Comment: I don't think it works.. It seems like hard coded . There are multiple files so need different solution .